# Why scaling data is very important in neural network(LSTM)

Tags: neural-network, lstm, backpropagation

I am writing my master thesis about how to apply LSTM neural network in time series. In my experiment, i found out that scaling data can have a great impact on the result. For example, when i use a tanh activation function, and the value range is between -1 and 1, the model seems to converge faster and the validation error also does not jump dramatically after each epoch.

Does anyone know is there any mathmetical explanation for that? Or is there any papers already explain about this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question reminds me of a picture used in our class, but you can find a similar one from [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/xx3Da/gradient-descent-in-practice-i-feature-scaling) at 3:02.

[image]

In the picture above you can see obviously that the path on the left is much longer than that on the right. The scaling is applied to the left to become the right one.

Comment: Hi, can i know the source of your picture to check exactly the explanation why the gradient can find the optimum that fast on the right side? Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/xx3Da/gradient-descent-in-practice-i-feature-scaling). Actually the I got it from the slide used in our class and no source is there. I've just searched the Google Image for that.

Comment: @LernerZhang Well the picture is just for linear regression? All sources use such kind of contour plots but in many cases the contours of the loss function don't have to have this shape. How one can show mathematically that for all loss functions feature scaling is useful for gradient descent?

Answer (score 0):

may the point is *nonlinearity*. my approach is from chaos theory ( fractals , multifractals,... ) and the range of input and parameter values of a nonlinear dynamical system have strong influence on the system behavior. this is because of the nonlinearity, in case of `tanh` the type of nonlinearity in the interval [-1,+1] is different than in other intervals, i.e. in the range [10,*infinity*) it is approx. a constant.

any nonlinear dynamical system is only valid in a specific range for both parameters and initial value, see i.e. the *logistic map*. Depending on the range of parameter values and initial values the behavior of the logistic map is **completely different**, this is the *sensitivity to initial conditions*
RNNs can be regarded as nonlinear self-referential systems.

in general there are some remarkable similarities between nonlinear dynamical systems and neural networks, i.e. the **fading memory** property of Volterra series models in Nonlinear Systems Identification and the **vanishing gradient** in recurrent neural networks

strongly chaotic systems have the *sensitivity to initial conditions* property and it is not possible to reproduce this heavily nonlinear behavior neither by Volterra series nor by RNNs because of the fading memory, resp. the vanishing gradient

so the mathematical background could be that a nonlinearity is more 'active' in the range of a specific intervall while linearity is equally active anywhere ( it is linear or approx constant )

in the context of RNNs and monofractality / multifractality **scaling** has two different meanings. This is especially confusing because RNNs and nonlinear, self-referential systems are deeply linked

- in the context of RNNs *scaling* means a **limiting of the range** of
  input or output values in the sense of an *affine transformation*
- in context of monofractality / multifractality *scaling* means that
  the output of the nonlinear system has a *specific structure* that is
  scale invariant in case of monofractals, self-affine in case of self-affine fractals ... where the *scale* is equivalent to a 'zoom level'

The link between RNNs and nonlinear self-referential systems is that they are both exactly that, nonlinear and self-referential.

in general *sensitivity to initial conditions* ( which is related to the **sensitivity to scaling** in RNNs ) and *scale invariance* in the resulting structures ( output ) only appears in **nonlinear** self-referential systems

the following paper is a good summary for multifractal and monofractal scaling in the output of a nonlinear self-referential system ( not to be confused with the scaling of input and output of RNNs ) : http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~gang/eprints/eprintLovejoy/neweprint/Aegean.final.pdf

in this paper is a direct link between nonlinear systems and RNN : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4107715/ - *Nonlinear System Modeling with Random Matrices: Echo State Networks Revisited*

Comment: Unfortunately this does not actually answer the question. The use of normalized inputs/outputs it is just to make the learning problem easier as all weights learn at the same rate.

Comment: You mean that all the weights at different layers learn at the same rate?

Comment: edited the answer because it was confusing, *scaling* has two different meanings in context of RNN and fractality / multifractality. for even more confusion RNN and nonlinear self-referential systems ( fractal systems ) are deeply linked ...